# Difference between network diagram and network topology?

Tags: networking

Well, the question is self-explanatory, but I just want to know the difference between a network diagram and a network topology (If there's any). I'm fairly new to network design and I have to present my current progress to judges of a networking competition, I want to make sure that I don't confuse and embarrass myself in front of my teachers, classmates and judges.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Network Topology is the actual design of a network.  A Network Diagram is a diagram (drawing) of a network.

[Network Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology):

> Network topology is the arrangement of the various elements (links, nodes, etc.) of a computer network. Essentially, it is the topological structure of a network and may be depicted physically or logically.

[Network Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network_diagram):

> A computer network diagram is a [schematic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematic) depicting the nodes and connections amongst nodes in a computer network.

Comment: Thank you, short but great answer. You saved me some headaches.

Answer (score 0):

a network topology describes the arrangement of various network types as links or nodes depicted logically(how data and information flows within the network) or physically(how they are connected together with cables) whereas network types are basically a collection of entities that share a network.